# Analytic derivatives of LegendreP[a, z] w.r.t. a at a = 0?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am interested in finding analytic expressions for various derivatives of the `LegendreP[a,z]` w.r.t. `a` at `a = 0`. Making use of its hypergeometric representation I was able to find

```
Derivative[1, 0][LegendreP][0, z] == Log[(1 + z)/2]
```

The Wolfram functions webpage has a [representation for the derivatives](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendrePGeneral/20/02/01/0001/) in terms of sums. For `ν = 0` and `m = 1` that formula seems to reduce to

```
Sum[((-1)^(1 + k) (z)^k BellB[k, -1])/(k^2 Gamma[k]), {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

which unfortunately does not seem to be resummable.

Overall, my question is:

> Is it possible to use Mathematica to quickly obtain analytic expressions for the derivatives of LegendreP[a,z] w.r.t a at a = 0? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: As it does not yet deserve to be an answer: I am doubtful that *Mathematica* can do this. Altho there are explicit formulae for low-order derivatives, to get arbitrary derivatives, one has to switch to the ${}_2 F_1$ representation and consider derivatives with respect to the parameters, [which can get complicated](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/39/395208).